# What do you call an equation that is impossible to algebraically solve?

Tags: trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, education

For example...

$$3.5=\sin{(x)}+\frac{\cos{(x)}}{\ln{(x)}+\sin{(x)}}$$

So your options to solving such a thing are iteration and other numerical methods. Does an equation that's not solvable algebraically have a specific name?

Comment: I would just call it "an equation for which we don't know a closed form solution".  It's also a transcendental equation, but some of those do have closed form solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "algebraically"? In the strictest sense, the word you are looking for is "transcendental" - meaning the solution is not the solution to any polynomial equation. However, $\sin(1)$ is a transcendental number, so this may be a broader category of things than you want.

Comment: You can use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts ;) Try this… `$$3.5=\sin(x)+\frac{\cos(x)}{\ln(x)+\sin(x)}$$`

Comment: Not having a closed-form solution is not the same thing as being unsolvable, @Arthur

Comment: @Arthur The problem with "unsolvable" is that solutions do exist (e.g. approximately $0.6916326914$), it's just that you can't write down a formula for a solution in terms of well-known functions.

Answer (score -1):

These are called [transcendental equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation). When you have a polynomial equation that you cannot solve, then you say that the equation "is not solvable by radicals."

Comment: Any reason for the dv?

Comment: Some transcendental equations have closed form solution.